# PC visibility in local network

Tags: wireless, networking, webserver, localhost

The thing is my pc with ubuntu installed is not visible in local network. I want to test web-app which is working on my pc (localhost:8000). From my phone destination is unreachable. Should i allow somewhere my pc to be visible?

How to do troubleshooting of this problem?

On windows everything worked fine so network is configured correctly.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more on the network between the PC's and phone along with with what type of web server you use to host web.. etc. This will help us to guide you further.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know the IP address of your PC and then access the web app with http://:8000

You can find out your ip address by running `ifconfig` in a terminal.

Comment: Yeah im trying to connect through IP:PORT :) Using localhost only locally :)